# Add class to every last-item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add that class "last-item" every last li.

Im trying this but without sucess:

```
<script>
$(".cbp-tm-submenu .product-categories li .children li:last-child").addClass("last-item");
<script>
```

I tried put on header and on footer.

HTML:

```
<ul class="cbp-tm-submenu">
<img class="backgroundtooltiptop" alt="background tooltip" src="http://localhost:8888/era420/wp-content/themes/era420/images/tooltipbackgroundtop.png">
    <li id="woocommerce_product_categories-4" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">
        <ul class="product-categories">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-16 current-cat cat-parent">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/era420/categoria-produto/lancamentos/">Lançamentos</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-17">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8888/era420/categoria-produto/lancamentos/teste/">teste</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-18">...</li>
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-19">...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<img class="backgroundtooltipbot" alt="background tooltip bot" src="http://localhost:8888/era420/wp-content/themes/era420/images/tooltipbackgroundbot.png">
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your `HTML` structure look like?

Comment: Have you tried placing this into your css file (minus the jQuery stuff)?

Comment: First thing to do is check whether the code is executed at all and then check which elements are selected. Those are basic debugging steps you have to do on your own. I'm not sure what you are expecting of us now.

Comment: Instead of adding the class, why not just use li:lat-child and style it?

Comment: I update the HTML, i using li:last-child does not work in some browsers, is better do this on server, all right?

thanks

Comment: You could also try this: `$(".cbp-tm-submenu .product-categories li .children li").last().addClass("last-item");`

Comment: Actually, to be fair this already works... http://jsfiddle.net/ctFws/

Comment: It is not a valid list with img placed as first and last child elements to ul.

Comment: I trid this scrowler, but does not work

Comment: Ok i ll try this jsfiddle

Comment: @StepanParunashvili I think you meant `li:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

This is enough:

```
$(".cbp-tm-submenu li:last-child").addClass("last-item");
```